# parse MapQuest XML response

Tags: c#, xml

here is the xml returned :

```
<IncidentsResponse>
  <Incidents>
    <Incident>
      <id>920959670</id>
      <type>1</type>
      <severity>3</severity>
      <eventCode>701</eventCode>
      <lat>35.91411</lat>
      <lng>-86.82417</lng>
      <startTime>2014-03-01T01:00:00.000-05:00</startTime>
      <endTime>2016-06-16T00:59:00.000-04:00</endTime>
      <shortDesc>
        I-65 : Maintenance work between Exit 59 TN-840 and Exit 65 TN-96
      </shortDesc>
      <fullDesc>
        Intermittent lane closures due to maintenance work on I-65 both ways between Exit 59     TN-840 and Exit 65 TN-96.
      </fullDesc>
      <delayFromTypical>0.0</delayFromTypical>
      <delayFromFreeFlow>0.0</delayFromFreeFlow>
      <distance>12.09</distance>
      <iconURL>https://api.mqcdn.com/mqtraffic/const_mod.png</iconURL>
    </Incident>
  </Incidents>
</IncidentsResponse>
```

I want to extract this into two brief descriptors, obtained from shortDesc and severity. Here is my C# attempt so far :

```
string[] incidentsDscrp = { };
string[] severity = { };
int count = 0;


XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(traffData);

foreach (var incidents in doc.Descendants("Incident"))
{
    incidentsDscrp[count] = incidents.Element("shortDesc").Value;
    severity[count] = incidents.Element("severity").Value;
    count++; 
}

trafficLabel.Text = "";
for (int a = 0; a < incidentsDscrp.Length; a++)
{
    trafficLabel.Text += incidentsDscrp[a];
    trafficLabel.Text += severity[a];
}
```

Basically I want to store descriptions of incidents in the incidentsDscrp array and severity level in the severity array, and then add them as text to a winforms label.

Edit : My error is that index was outside bounds of the array at the

```
severity[count] = incidents.Element("severity").value;
```

line

Comment: I think you need to show more code.  Where does `count` come from and where does `severity` get initialized?  While you are at it you can fix the indenting of your code block.

Comment: okay, just edited it, I tried initializing the arrays as both new string[#] and { };

Comment: Use List<string> and List<int> instead of arrays

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Parallel collections is a terrible way to store data like that (unless you really know what you're doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but you're doing it wrong.

First of all, storing data like that (in parallel collections), is a really bad idea. You should read following blog post by Jon Skeet: [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections.aspx).

Now, to solve your problem. Here is a little LINQ to XML query which allows you to get all you need from XML document:

```
var items = from i in xDoc.Root.Element("Incidents").Elements("Incident")
            select new
            {
                ShortDescription = (string)i.Element("shortDesc"),
                Severity = (int)i.Element("severity")
            };
```

You can join all the items into a string using `String.Join`:

```
var text = String.Join(",", items.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.ShortDescription.Trim(), x.Severity.ToString())));
```

For your sample document, `text`s value is:

> I-65 : Maintenance work between Exit 59 TN-840 and Exit 65 TN-96: 3

Change separator of format string to get desired result. Now you can assign it to the label:

```
trafficLabel.Text = text;
```

Comment: much better than mine, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use following to parse and create a label -

```
 from c in trafficData.Descendants("Incident")       
    select new
    {
        ShortDescription = c.Element("shortDesc").Value,
        Severity = c.Element("severity").Value
    }).Aggregate((a,b) => a.ShortDescription +": " + a.Severity +", " 
                        + b.ShortDescription +": " + b.Severity);
```